# Xamarin.Form FlowListView - NullReferenceException when refresh the list

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

**Steps to reproduce:**

Load the collection from database or another source
Remove a item from database
Refresh the list using Pull-to-Refresh for example
Result:
App crashes.

**Observations:**

If the new refresh returns the same quantity of items, so the app doesn't crash;
If the new refresh returns zero items, so the app doesn't crash;
If I leave the page and navigate to it again, the error does not occur

**Versions:**

DLToolkit.Forms.Controls.FlowListView: 2.0.11

Xamarin.Forms: 3.4.0.1008975

**Error:**

> 11-20 23:38:07.111 I/MonoDroid(10001): System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 11-20
>   23:38:07.111 I/MonoDroid(10001): at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.DataTemplateExtensions.CreateContent
>   (Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate self, System.Object item,
>   Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject container) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\DataTemplateExtensions.cs:19 11-20
>   23:38:07.111 I/MonoDroid(10001): at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList2[TView,TItem].ActivateContent
>   (System.Int32 index, System.Object item) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedItemsList.cs:534 11-20
>   23:38:07.111 I/MonoDroid(10001): at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList2[TView,TItem].CreateContent
>   (System.Int32 index, System.Object item, System.Boolean insert)
>   [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedItemsList.cs:543
>   11-20 23:38:07.111 I/MonoDroid(10001): at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList2[TView,TItem].GetOrCreateContent
>   (System.Int32 index, System.Object item) [0x00023] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedItemsList.cs:602 11-20
>   23:38:07.111 I/MonoDroid(10001): at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Internals.TemplatedItemsList2[TView,TItem].get_Item
>   (System.Int32 index) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedItemsList.cs:337 11-20
>   23:38:07.111 I/MonoDroid(10001): at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.GetCellsFromPosition
>   (System.Int32 position, System.Int32 take) [0x0003b] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ListViewAdapter.cs:538
>   11-20 23:38:07.111 I/MonoDroid(10001): at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.GetCellForPosition
>   (System.Int32 position) [0x00000] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ListViewAdapter.cs:453
>   11-20 23:38:07.111 I/MonoDroid(10001): at
>   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.GetView (System.Int32
>   position, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup
>   parent) [0x0006d] in
>   D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\Renderers\ListViewAdapter.cs:225
>   11-20 23:38:07.111 I/MonoDroid(10001): at
>   Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.n_GetView_ILandroid_view_View_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_
>   (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Int32
>   position, System.IntPtr native_convertView, System.IntPtr
>   native_parent) [0x00018] in <263adecfa58f4c449f1ff56156d886fd>:0 11-20
>   23:38:07.111 I/MonoDroid(10001): at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   System.Object.287e09fa-fd7a-4426-ae0c-4254aa73f3b9(intptr,intptr,int,intptr,intptr)

Thanks in advance

**Edit 1:**

The code:

**XAML:**

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="1" SeparatorVisibility="Default" BackgroundColor="White" HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                    FlowLoadingCommand="{Binding LoadUnreadNotificationsCommand}" FlowTotalRecords="{Binding TotalUnread}" FlowIsLoadingInfiniteEnabled="True"
                    FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding NotificationSelectedCommand}" FlowIsLoadingInfinite="{Binding IsBusy}"
                    FlowItemsSource="{Binding UnreadNotifications}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}" RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadUnreadNotificationsCommand}">

    <flv:FlowListView.FlowEmptyTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource NoData}">
                    <controls:FontAwesomeSolidIcon Text="{x:Static core:Icon.Unread}" Style="{StaticResource IconDashboardLabel}" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="20" TextColor="#cccccc" />
                    <Label Text="Não existem por ler" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="#cccccc" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowEmptyTemplate>

    <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <list:Card />
        </DataTemplate>
    </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

</flv:FlowListView>
```

C#:

```
public async Task LoadNotifications(bool read)
{


if (this.AcquireTapLock())
    {


var notificationsResponse = await ApiManager.GetNotifications(new PaginateNotificationsModel(Settings.IdUser, read, 0, Constants.ItemsByPage, string.Empty));

        if (notificationsResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var response = await notificationsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListNotificationResponseModel>(response));

            if (result.Status == ApiResponseStatus.Ok)
            {
                if (read)
                {
                    ReadNotifications = new ObservableRangeCollection<NotificationModel>(result.Notifications);
                    TotalRead = result.CountAfterFilter;
                }
                else
                {
                    UnreadNotifications = new ObservableRangeCollection<NotificationModel>(result.Notifications);
                    TotalUnread = result.CountAfterFilter;
                }
            }
        }

        IsBusy = false;
        this.ReleaseTapLock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hrm, i think i will upvote for a nicely formatted question. well done, however some code would be nice

Comment: @TheGeneral I added some code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the cause, add mode as OneWayToSource in the FlowListView control that keeps the th total count of the list which is a reasonable way like this:

`FlowTotalRecords="{Binding yourViewmodel.Count, Mode=OneWayToSource}"`